# What is HTTPD exactly?

Tags: apache, http, cgi

I mean is "httpd" only used by Apache for the download of the software or is it used by other websites as well? Also is it necessary to have httpd to run "cgi" or not? 
And why does Apache use httpd to download the http server instead of having it in a file on their http website?

Comment: Hyper-Text Transfer Protocol Daemon. generic acronym, but usually means the actual webserver application software/server running on a machine, e.g. Apache, IIS, nginx, etc...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[Apache HTTPD](https://httpd.apache.org/) is an [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) [server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)) [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) produced by the [Apache Foundation](http://www.apache.org/foundation/). It is a piece of software that listens for network requests (which are expressed using the Hypertext Transfer Protocol) and responds to them.

It is open source and [many entities use it to host their websites](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2015/12/31/december-2015-web-server-survey.html).

Other HTTP servers are available (including [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) which is designed for running server side programs written in Java (which don't use CGI)).

[CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) is a protocol that allows an HTTP server to use an external piece of software to determine how to respond to a request instead of simply returning the contents of a static file. Many HTTP servers support the CGI protocol.

You can use CGI without an HTTP server, but this typically has few uses beyond allowing a developer to perform command line testing of the CGI program. (You certainly can't interact with it directly from a web browser).

Comment: Could we say that HTTPD is the program called Apache that runs for example on my computer?

Comment: That's a bit like saying "Car is the motor vehicle called Ford that runs on my road", but "Apache" is a common alias for Apache HTTPD and it commonly runs with a process name of `apache` or `apache.exe`.

Comment: Is the httpd.apache.org just the way they named the subdomain or is it a protocol like ftp?

Comment: It's the name of the subdomain. The protocol in a URL is followed by `://`

Answer (score 4):

HTTP Daemon is a software program that runs in the background of a web server and waits for the incoming server requests. The daemon answers the request automatically and serves the hypertext and multimedia documents over the Internet using HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Httpd is basically a web server used for handling requests and delivering static content. While CGI is a protocol which adds a scripts with the request and based on the script the content is delivered instead of simply returning a static content. So it is not necessary to use CGI with apache httpd but for delivering a dynnmic content httpd and cgi are used together.

Also using httpd with cgi is a very heavy process of delivering dynamic content as it creates and destroys process with every request response cycle, there are many other efficient alternatives with latest technology.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPd - HyperText Transfer Protocol Daemon

HTTPd is a software program, that usually runs in the background, as a process.
It plays the role of server in a client-server model using HTTP and/or HTTPS network protocols.

HTTPd waits for the incoming client requests and for each request it answers by replying with requested information.

Following are some commonly used HTTPd

1. Apache
2. BusyBox
3. CERN HTTPd
4. Lighttpd
5. Ngnix